# Trying to create a log in system but getting error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) "

Tags: login, errors

I have directly copied the code from a tutorail video that I have been watching and even got a hold of his code files and directly copied and pasted just to make sure but this error keeps popping up. It seems to be limited to this body of

```
// Checks for a valid email

  else
if
    {
    (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=" . $username);
        exit();
        }
```

If you have any input on where I went wrong please help, as I am new at this

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php – That's basic PHP. Remove the `else` or make it `elseif` if it is part of a larger control structure above it.

Comment: You have `{` after `if` and this is the cause of the error. See the link that gave leymannx.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks completely mangled. Try:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=" . $username);
   exit();
}
```

Count up the `if` and `else` and make sure they surround the code correctly. Although you can skip the `{}` when using a single line of code, it's good practice to always add them in, so you can avoid messy, error prone code like this.

```
if($value = 10) {
   // Your code
} else {
   // Something else
}
```

Finally, this isn't anything to do with WordPress.